# What is the does this mean ls = new LocalServerSocket("mycomputer")?

Tags: android, linux, sockets

I'm trying to understand Sockets and I see this basic class initialization that goes like this

```
LocalServerSocket ls = new LocalServerSocket("mycomputer");
```

What does "mycomputer" represent ?

I read the Android api for Localserversocket and it says it's a AF_LOCAL linux namespace, which to me seems like the name of a directory. What I want to know is how will I be able to communicate with a linux namespace from a windows computer to initialize a LocalServerSocket and how do I even create a AF_Local namespace on a linux machine?

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to know is how will I be able to communicate with a linux namespace from a windows computer

You can't. Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket):

> A Unix domain socket or IPC socket (inter-process communication socket) is a data communications endpoint for exchanging data between processes executing within the same host operating system

Comment: Ok. Then how can I developed an app using localserversockets on a windows computer?

Comment: @MichaelNana: You don't. `LocalServerSocket` is **local**. It is for IPC, which means it is only usable on the Android device itself.

Comment: Hmmmmmmm. Ok, that actually makes sense. So then if a programmer uses a localserversocket in their app, how do they know that every android phone has AF_LOCAl called "mycomputer"? Does that app create that socket first or what?

Comment: @MichaelNana: "how do they know that every android phone has AF_LOCAl called "mycomputer"?" -- All IPC/RPC requires *a priori* knowledge of how to bootstrap the communications. For example, you seem to be using a Web browser, communicating to the `stackoverflow.com` Web server. How does `stackoverflow.com` know that it has a server socket open on port 80? Because it created it. How does the browser know to try port 80 on `stackoverflow.com`? Because that's the default. With `LocalServerSocket`, both client and server need to agree on the name.